# MYSQL Select Query where i want two row base on where condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
/* First query */
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE ((MONTH >=  '10' || 
        MONTH <=  '12' && YEAR =  '2015') && 
       (MONTH >=  '1' || 
        MONTH <=  '3' && YEAR =  '2016' ))
GROUP BY YEAR

/* Second query */
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE ((MONTH >= '1' || 
        MONTH <= '3' && YEAR = '2015') &&
       (MONTH >= '5' || 
        MONTH <= '10' && YEAR = '2015'))
GROUP BY YEAR
```

The first query returns two rows based on year. But the second query returns only one row.

I know I done based on group by year but I want two rows which fulfill my two where condition matches.

Any other suggestion?

Here is output.

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7tZG.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M411m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this way:-

```
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE (((MONTH >=  '1' || MONTH <=  '3') && YEAR =  '2015') ||
((MONTH >=  '5' || MONTH <=  '10') && YEAR =  '2015'))
GROUP BY YEAR
```

OR

```
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE (MONTH >=  '1' || MONTH <=  '3') && YEAR =  '2015' 
GROUP BY YEAR
Union all
SELECT YEAR, SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM accounts
WHERE (MONTH >=  '5' || MONTH <=  '10') && YEAR =  '2015' 
GROUP BY YEAR
```

Comment: no you go on wrong trake 
in first query i got two column and in second querry i got one row because of group by year ..

is there any query to get two row from my two where condition like
WHERE 
1.(((MONTH >=  '1' || MONTH <=  '3') && YEAR =  '2015') ||
2.((MONTH >=  '5' || MONTH <=  '10') && YEAR =  '2015'))

so how can i get two row any solution

Comment: union all will fix that in second query

Comment: thank you so much chandan you save my time